# Dynamic invocation of WSDL in c++

Tags: c++, soap, open-source

Im looking for c/c++ library which enable me to invoke WS without generating
stubs in the client , what i found until now is only this :
https://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdlpull/

which i don't sure how much it have support to complex wsdl .
is there more feature rich WS c++/c client ?

Comment: You have been a member for a long time, asked a lot of question, and have relatively high reputation. And yet you still ask questions like this? Maybe it's time for a refresher of ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)?

Comment: where can i ask questions like this in the www?